# Define constant from expression

Tags: verilog

I know I can define constants in Verilog very statically:

```
`define FETCH_1 0
`define FETCH_2 1
`define ADD_1 2
...
`define PUSH_2 134
```

Is it possible to create a constant from an expression, e.g. something similar to that (Java syntax):

```
public static final int FETCH_1 = 0
public static final int FETCH_2 = FETCH_1 + 1;
public static final int ADD_1 = FETCH_2 + 1;
...
public static final int PUSH_2 = PUSH_1 + 1;
```

so it is easy to later add a constant in the middle without having to change all following constants? Or should I use a different language that creates a constants file with `define` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use constants in expressions when defining other constants.

```
`define ADD_1 `FETCH_2 + 1
```

When using `` `define `` macros, you need to use the `` ` `` prefix when *using* the macro.

This is also possible with constants declared as `parameter`:

```
parameter FETCH_1 = 0;
parameter FETCH_2 = FETCH_1 + 1;
parameter ADD_1   = FETCH_2 + 1;
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 6.20 *Constants*

Answer (score 1):

It is best to avoid using `` `define `` for defining constant expressions. Some problems they have are compile order dependencies and lack localization of scopes (can't put them in a package). They are also difficult to debug when you have made mistakes.

In SystemVerilog, you can use a `parameter` or the `let` construct.

```
parameter int FETCH_1 = 0
localparam int FETCH_2 = FETCH_1 + 1;
localparam int ADD_1 = FETCH_2 + 1;
...
localparam int PUSH_2 = PUSH_1 + 1;
```

The difference between a `parameter` and `localparam` is that a parameter's value can bet overridden in a module/interface instance, whereas a `localparam` cannot be overridden.

The `let` construct is almost like a macro, but can be defined local to a scope, and its definition must be a syntactically legal expression. It is not text substitution.

```
let FETCH_1 = 0
let FETCH_2 = FETCH_1 + 1;
let ADD_1 = FETCH_2 + 1;
...
let PUSH_2 = PUSH_1 + 1;
```

Comment: What part of your answer works for Verilog as I'm not yet using SystemVerilog?

Comment: @ThomasS. Parameters and localparams are from Verilog without the explicit types. BTW you tagged your question with [tag:system-verilog], so I assumed that is what you are using.